# Can't access array element in HTMLBars template

Tags: ember.js, htmlbars

As I understand it you should be able to access array elments via `{{array.[0].something}}`.

I am trying to use this but it is not working.  In my case, claims is an `async` relationship of invoice.

```
{{invoice.claims.length}} //Returns "1" as expected
```

All these are blank

```
{{invoice.claims.[0]}}
{{invoice.claims.[0].claimNumber}}
{{invoice.claims.content.[0]}}
{{invoice.claims.content.[0].claimNumber}}
```

I can see the claim has been downloaded in ember-inspector but for some reason the binding has not worked.

### Update

I got it working using the following

```
{{invoice.claims.firstObject.claimNumber}}
```

Still interested why the above works but `{{invoice.claims.[0].claimNumber}}` does not though.

Comment: Can you post your model/route that is providing the `{{invoice}}` object to the page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's is possible to access the elements of an array through handlebars like you have described. Here's a [Twiddle](http://ember-twiddle.com/d9fc370d7f177cd71b65) demonstrating it.

The problem is in another part of your code. Provide more information to see where it can be.

Comment: It looks like what he's doing is trying to access properties on a model, doesn't look like a regular array.

Comment: Well I got it working this way `{{invoice.claims.firstObject.claimNumber}}`. Why this would work but `{{invoice.claims.[0].claimNumber}}` does not is a little weird.  I can say that `{{invoice.claims.content}}` was a ManyArray so maybe this has something to do with it.